# Color Chart Columns by Cell Color Error

Tags: vba, excel, charts, colors

I am trying create a chart using cell colors from the active cells on a specific worksheet. When using the macro provided below I find that only some of the assigned cell RGB color codes match to the chart. I am not sure why some colors would match and some would not. The correct colors display in the chart when I manually enter the color codes. Is there something I am leaving out of this macro or an extra step I need to take?

I am using Excel 2016 for this project.

```
Sub ColorChartColumnsbyCellColor()
With Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
Set vAddress = ActiveSheet.Range(Split(Split(.Formula, ",")(1), "!")(1))
For i = 1 To vAddress.Cells.Count
.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 
ThisWorkbook.Colors(vAddress.Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex)
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem comes from this line `Set vAddress = ActiveSheet.Range(Split(Split(.Formula, ",")(1), "!")(1)) ` . Unfortunately, I don't know what you're trying to do with that nested split so I don't know how to help you. Try to `Assert` that line to see if you're getting the expected result.

Comment: If any of the colors you're trying to pick up from the worksheet are coming from conditional formatting then you need to look at `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`   Those colors will not be reflected in `Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex` - that will return the "base/resting" color of the cell without any CF changes applied

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning a color index to the RGB property. Color indexes have nothing to do with Red Green Blue. Besides, @Tim William's has a point: conditional formatting may play a role in what you're doing.

Try this code, which assigns the Color property to the RGB property:

```
Sub ColorChartColumnsbyCellColor()
    With Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
        Set vAddress = ActiveSheet.Range(Split(Split(.Formula, ",")(1), "!")(1))

        For i = 1 To vAddress.Cells.Count
            'Comment the line below and uncomment the next one to take conditional formatting into account.
            .Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vAddress.Cells(i).Interior.Color
            '.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vAddress.Cells(i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't `.Points(i).Interior.Color = vaddress.Cells(i).Interior.Color` be enough inside the For loop?

Comment: While it compiles and works, Intellisense doesn't pick up `.Interior` for the `Point` class. I assume it's deprecated.

Comment: I was actually more bothered by the `thisworkbook.colors()` part - what is that doing? to me it seems as if the arguments inside should be enough.

Comment: OMG LOL! Updating code... thanks hahaha... IOU some rep points now.

Comment: This worked perfectly, there was no conditional formatting in this instance. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @pb3213 The best way to thank us is to upvote elements that were helpful, and select the best answer using the big green checkmark.

Comment: You can use `.Points(i).Interior.Color`, but for IntelliSense to see it you probably need to Show Hidden Members in the Object Browser.